# Matlab solve linear system with condition to x

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, eigenvector

I have a matrix `A` and an eigenvalue=`1`. Now I want to compute the eigenvector (without eig()).
I have to solve `(A-I)x=0`. With the help of a QR decomposition I have to solve `Rx=0`. Let´s say `R` is a `nxn` Matrix.

```
x=R\zeros(n,1)
```

does not work obviously because I just get the zero vector. That is why I want to set `x(n)=1` but how can I solve that in Matlab?

Merry Chrismas.

Comment: Can you show us what the matrix looks like?  You obviously can't solve it that way because there is more than one possible eigenvector for the associated eigenvalue (within a scalar multiple).  As an example, consult this website as an illustration for solving for eigenvectors manually: http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/eigen2/eigen2.html